# How to implement makefile goal which relies on other makefile goal being invoked or not

Tags: bash, unix, makefile

My original use case rather complicated but could be distilled to the following:

```
a:
    export AAA=true

b:
    echo ${AAA}
ifdef AAA 
    echo "AAA mode is on."
else
    echo "AAA mode is off."
endif
```

What I want to achieve is to have conditional `b` target depends on whether `a` was invoked or not.

However behaviour is not intuitive and whilst `AAA=true make b` does work `make a b` does not work as intended (I prefer the latter).

Any helpful advises will be appreciated!

Comment: You can't; recipes execute in separate processes, and you can only pass environment variables from parent to child, not from sibling to sibling.

Comment: "Whether `a` was invoked..." Do you mean whether `a` has already been executed, or whether `a` is on Make's list of targets to be rebuilt, or something else? And *why* do you want the behavior of the `b` rule to vary this way? This might be the XY problem.

Comment: > "whether a is on Make's list of targets to be rebuilt"

^ this is my scenario

> "This might be the XY problem"

^ Any good link to what XY problem is?

Comment: This is literally the first google hit for me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: doh, one day I'll learn to use google before asking questions. Thanks @tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to restrict yourself to GNU make you can use the `eval` function.  I don't generally think this is a good idea and I agree with Beta that this may be an XY problem, but:

```
AAA = false

a:
        $(eval AAA = true)

b:
        echo ${AAA}
```

Note you definitely *cannot* use make preprocessor statements like `ifeq` or `ifdef`: those are evaluated *as the makefile is parsed*, even ones that are contained within a recipe, which obviously happens well before any recipe is invoked which might set `AAA` etc.

ETA:

Here's an example of the above makefile in action to show it works:

```
$ make b
false

$ make b a
false

$ make a b
true
```

As mentioned in comments elsewhere, the value of `AAA` is reset in the recipe for `b`, *IFF* the recipe for `a` has already been invoked.  That's how I interpreted your request *What I want to achieve is to have conditional `b` target depends on whether `a` was invoked or not*, but maybe you had a different behavior in mind.

Comment: Ok, taking that back. This answer is indeed "all rounder" when it comes to my scenario and the like.

Alternative solution is to rely on `${MAKECMDGOALS}` but it requires makefile goal to come from user input (which is my use case but I didn't mention that explicitly when asking question).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was trying to play with evals (didn't work) and file markers (not ideal because I have hierarchy of makefiles and some of them invoked twice hence `$(shell rm -f .target-marker)` invoked multiple times) and I think for my use case the best is to explore current goals invoked:

```
a:
    #market target

b:
    @if [[ "${MAKECMDGOALS}" = a* ]]; then \
        echo "AAA mode is on"; \
    else \
        echo "AAA mode is off"; \
    fi;
```

`MAKECMDGOALS` contains all goals and I simply can check if certain goal was in list or not.

Comment: There's much wrong with this solution.  But before that, this is exactly what we meant by "XY problem".  You said "conditional target `b` depends on whether `a` was invoked" without saying that `a` had to be specified on the make command line.  Knowing whether some random target in the makefile was run or not is much harder than knowing whether the user specified a target on the command line.

Comment: Beyond that, this is very non-portable: you're using bash-specific features in your recipes but make always invokes `/bin/sh`.  If you run this makefile on any system where `/bin/sh` is not bash, it won't work.  If you want to use this solution you must set `SHELL = /bin/bash` specifically in your makefile.  Beyond that, this will only work if the user specifies `a` as the first target on the command line: what if they run `make x a b` instead?  Or what if another target starting with `a` is used?  You should use a make function like this: `@if [ "$(filter a,$(MAKECMDGOALS))" = a ]; then ...`

Comment: FYI, the `eval` solution absolutely does work.  Maybe your version of GNU make was too old?  `eval` was introduced in GNU make 3.80, released in 2002.  One other difference between that and this solution: the `eval` version only works if the recipe for the `a` target was actually invoked (because `a` was not up to date), which is exactly what you asked for.  However the `MAKECMDGOALS` version will match if the user specified the target on the command line, _even if it was up-to-date so the recipe wasn't invoked_.  Maybe that's what you wanted, but your question said "`a` was invoked".  Cheers!

Comment: @MadScientist #1 - ok, "user specified" goal was implicit in my mind. Sorry for that, I should have been more explicit that it's user drive choice.

Comment: @MadScientist #2 - please use this as reference example. Actual target names are more descriptive and regexp could be tuned to allow pattern matching of `make b withA` way of invocation. Whilst #1 is legit comment I consider second part #2 as nitpick. As for bash specific - I'm ok with that restriction.

Comment: @MadScientist #3 eval didn't work for me out of the box (also I tried similar eval solutions before coming and asking SO question). GNU version is 4.2.2 for me (I'm on latest macbook hardware, latest MacOS High Sierra and latest xCode). 
Cheers!

Comment: The latest version of GNU make is 4.2.1: I don't know where 4.2.2 comes from.  I'd be shocked if you got GNU make >3.81 with MacOS/Xcode: Apple hates GPLv3.  Maybe you installed a newer version via macports or brew?  It's fine if your needs are restricted but SO is also for other people reading the question and answers, and they may have different requirements, so portability, extensibility, etc. are important to think about here.  Using `filter` is a better method all around.

Comment: `eval` works, but differently than `MAKECMDGOALS` as my answer and comments mention.  Without an example of what you tried, along with the results you got and why they weren't what you wanted, it's hard to say exactly what the issue was.  But since you got what you wanted it's moot anyway!

Comment: @MadScientist #4, I indeed have 4.2.1. I must've misread output yesterday (off by one problem I guess). `filter` is indeed better reflect intention in my case.

Comment: @MadScientist #5, well, I just tried to copy and paste answer "as-is": and it worked for me. Lesson learned - do not try to retype from SO and just copy&paste what was posted by smarter people.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expose one shell's environment to another, but you can use a flag file.

```
# Kludge: Force removal when make starts
$(shell rm -f .done-a)

a:
    : things
    touch .done-a

b:
    if [ -e .done-a ]; then : stuff ...;  \
    else : other stuff ...; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Two variations on your theme with a single definitions. As @tripleee said you can't pass externs, but you can have a common definition in the makefile. I also try to avoid empty shell variables where possible. In this case a straight up true/false value can be used.

```
#last definition "wins"
AAA=false
AAA=true

a:
    export AAA=$(AAA)

b:
    export AAA=$(AAA)
    echo $${AAA};        #note double dollar within shell commands
    $$AAA && echo "AAA mode is on." || echo "AAA mode is off."

nested_c:
    $(MAKE) AAA=$(AAA) c
```